# which part of the histogram refers to the rows of a 2 dimensional array while plotting graphs using matplot library?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to plot graphs b/w a 2 dimensional numpy array and bins. Before this I only plotted graphs using two lists. In histograms there will be three stacked bar corresponding to the no of columns in array `a`. I want to know that what the command `plt.hist` is doing with the no of rows of the array?

```
a= np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
print a

bins = 5
plt.hist(a, bins, normed=1, histtype='bar',stacked=True)
plt.title('stacked bar')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort answer: the rows correspond to the samples, the columns to the variables.

Long answer:

A histogram divides the range of values into `n` bins (5 in your example). Then, it counts the number of values that fall in each bin.

To illustrate, let's generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 20:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 20 + 1, 1000)
```

A histogram of these values, using 5 bins, will define the bins as follows:

bin 1: 0 to 4
bin 2: 4 to 8
bin 3: 8 to 12
bin 4: 12 to 16
bin 5: 16 to 20

Then, for each bin, it will count the number of values that fall into the corresponding range. Finally, it will plot the number of values in each bin as a bar chart:[image]

In the above example, I used a list (or 1d-array) of values. What if we use a 2D array? Then, the above histogram operation is repeated for each column:

```
b = np.random.randint(0, 21, 3000).reshape(1000, 3)
plt.hist(b, bins=5)
```

[image]

If you set `stacked=True`, the resulting histograms are plotted on top of each other:

```
plt.hist(b, bins=5, stacked=True)
```

[image]